# Python: Type Error, but I don't know what to change! Question for Someone who know many about Smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

I wanted to do an Email writer. I saw a tutorial and this came out:

```
import smtplib
import os

user = os.getenv("SMTP_USER")
pwd = os.getenv("SMTP_PWO")
mail_text = "Hallo, \n\ndas ist ein Test!\n\n"
subject = "Python Mail"

MAIL_FROM = "x.muelfellner@outlook.de"
RCPT_TO = input("Empfänger: ")
DATA = "From:%s\nTo:%s\nSubject:%s\n\n%" \
       (MAIL_FROM,RCPT_TO,subject,mail_text)
server = smtplib.SMTP("secure.emailsrvr.com:587")
server.starttls()
server.login(user,pwd)
server.sendmail(MAIL_FROM,RCPT_TO,DATA)
server.quit()
```

But when I'm running the code there's an Error. Here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Bookshelf/Pyton/SendEmail.py", line 12, in <module>
    (MAIL_FROM,RCPT_TO,subject,mail_text)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I don't know what i have to change! Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't related to smtplib; it's just a syntax error.

You're inadvertently trying to call a string (I removed the `\` continuation):

```
DATA = "From:%s\nTo:%s\nSubject:%s\n\n%"(MAIL_FROM,RCPT_TO,subject,mail_text)
```

It should be

```
DATA = "From:%s\nTo:%s\nSubject:%s\n\n%s" % (MAIL_FROM,RCPT_TO,subject,mail_text)
```

to format a string.